# Select from multiple tables shows no results if one is empty sqlite

Tags: android, sql, select, sqlite

I'm using this in android but using SQLite Studio 2.1.4 for testing.

I have two tables: A and B. 
A has 2 records and B has no records.

If I query

```
select * from A
```

I get the results in that table, which is fine.

If I query

```
select * from B
```

I get no results, which is also fine.

However, if I query:

```
select * from A, B
```

I also get no results, which is wrong... I should get the results from A, right?

Or is SQLite somewhat different from the other DBMS out there?

Answer (score 4):

SELECT * from A, B is a cartesian join of both tables. In other words every row in table A is joined to every row in table B. So if A has 5 rows and B has 10 rows, you end up with 50 rows in your results set. In this case, table B has zero rows hence it doesn't matter how many rows A contains, you get no rows back.

You will find the same behaviour in all relational databases.